# How to connect to mysql-server deployed on compute engine from local computer?

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-workbench, google-compute-engine

I want to connect to mysql-server deployed on compute engine with mysql workbench or with mysql-client from local computer. How can i do it?. I tried [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mysql-remote-access) .I am able to connect from other vm but not from my local computer. I am not able to connect from cloud-shell and app engine as well.

Comment: Does your server have an external IP ? Did you configure the Google Cloud firewall to allow incoming TCP connections to port 3306 from your IP ? Is the mysql-server actually running?

Comment: i got the solution @JordiMiralles. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple. make external ip for the the vm static. and change firewall settings to accept connections. make mysql to bind to external ip so that you can connect to mysql through the external ip.